# How to pass value to ASP.NET Core custom tag helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, custom-tags

I'm completely new with custom tag helper. After lots of searching all examples build and pass values but never get values from tag helper.

My Idea is to build a custom pager. So I need to know the number of pages `nop`. I don't know if I should add `dataset` attribute to pass the value of `nop` or there is another way.

I don't know really how the scenario should be. However, I'll try to explain my code here.

First

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "pagination")]
public class Pagerpagination : TagHelper
{
    public int nop { get; set; } // I should get number of pages
    public string BootstraPagination;
    public string pagination { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        BootstraPagination = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";

        for (int i = 0; i < nop; i++)
        {
            BootstraPagination += $"<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='{i}'>{i + 1}</a></li>";
        }

        BootstraPagination += "</ul></nav>";
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(BootstraPagination);
    }
}
```

After that to pass the value as I assume to use dataset

```
<pagination data-nop="5" />
```

then the expected result should be bootstrap pagination with 5 number of pages `nop`

```
<nav><ul class='pagination'>
   <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='0'>1</a></li>
   <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='1'>2</a></li>
   <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='2'>3</a></li>
   <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='3'>4</a></li>
   <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='4'>5</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass information through an attribute, define the attribute in your TagHelper (PascalCase) :

```
public int MyAttribute { get; set; }
```

And set it like that (kebab-case):

```
<pagination my-attribute="5"></pagination>
```

`Attributes` property in `[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "pagination")]` just define required attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I got the solution for this!

to pass value from the custom tag helper to void Process I should use `TagHelperContext context`.

eg:

```
string nop = context.AllAttributes["nop"].Value.ToString();
```

if need `int` value just parse

```
int nop = int.Parse(context.AllAttributes["nop"].Value.ToString());
```

usage:

```
<pagination nop="5"></pagination>
```